# How do I use SymPy to simplify by substitution a number of equations to get to a single simplified equation?

Tags: python, sympy, substitution, simplify

My question is exactly like the title of my post. Attached is an image with an example of what I would like to achieve.

[Description of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ItH7.jpg) I have updated this file after the original post and after the problem was solved to correct a typo.

Note `Vref` in the picture of the description is zero.

The attempts to get the SymPy functions mentioned to work failed.

Comment: Don't post images of code. Also, detail what you've tried before. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the solution you are looking for is really easy. First, you find `Vx` from `eq1`, substitutes it into `eq2` and solve it for `Vo`:

```py
from sympy import *
Vi, Vo, Vx = symbols("Vi, Vo, Vx")
R1, R2, R3, R4 = symbols("R1:5")

eq1 = Eq((0 - Vi) / R1, (Vi - Vx) / R2)
eq2 = Eq((Vi - Vx) / R2, Vx / R4 + (Vx - Vo) / R3)
Vx_expr = solve(eq1, Vx)[0]
Vo_expr = solve(eq2.subs(Vx, Vx_expr), Vo)[0]
Vo_expr
```

[image]

Now, if you want to transform it into the output you see on your screenshot, you have to use expression manipulation, which is pure masochism for a SymPy's novice. I'll show you how I'd do it.

In the following, you'll see several sympy's function in action. It is your job to read their documentation.

```py
Vo_expr = Vo_expr.expand().collect(Vi)
Vo_expr
```

[image]

Now, I want to see the order of the arguments of the big addition:

```py
Vo_expr.args[1].args
```

[image]

I select the terms that I need to modify:

```py
term1 = Add(*[t for i, t in enumerate(Vo_expr.args[1].args) if i in [3, 4]])
display(term1, term1.together())
```

[image]

```py
term2 = Add(*[t for i, t in enumerate(Vo_expr.args[1].args) if i in [1, 2]])
display(term2, term2.together())
```

[image]

Then, I substitute the terms with their modified forms:

```py
Vo_final = Vo_expr.subs({term1: term1.together(), term2: term2.together()})
Vo_final
```

[image]

Finally, I verify that the result is equal to the original expression:

```py
Vo_final.equals(Vo_expr)
# out: True
```

Comment: The solution provided by https://stackoverflow.com/users/2329968/davide-sd is spot on. Thank you for your effort. I will be using this for years to come.

Comment: Mark the reply as the solution to your question. :)